# Best approach to pass data between ItemProcessors in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I need to pass data related to processing an item in between item processors, I don't need to persist the data, what is the best approach (Note I'm currently using StepSynchronizationManager to access the stepExecution and store the data in ExecutionContext).

Comment: can u paste the code , i want to know how you are using StepSynchronizationManager.i needed for my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think, that your way - storing the data in StepExecutionContext - is a bad or not the best way ?

You could try it without saving the data in the StepExecution and instead change the items between the processors

```
public class FirstProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String, String> {...}


public class SecondProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String, OtherClass> {

  public OtherClass process(String item) throws Exception {

     return otherClassObjectWithDataForNextProcessor;

  }
}

public class ThirdProcessor implements ItemProcessor<OtherClass, TargetClass> {...}

public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<TargetClass> {...}
```

see [Spring Batch Doc - Chaining Item Processors](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#chainingItemProcessors)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, StepExecutionContext only holds serializable objects and besides it persists the data held in it, both behaviors are not desirable in my case. I guess the best approach is to wrap my Items with another class that also defines a map to hold non persistable processing context.